# How to make a logo single-colored?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, color-conversion

I'm trying to convert a bunch of company logos to one single color (not just black and white). It's for a website I'm working on, for the "We support those products" type of thing.

Here's what I'm starting with:

[image]

What I did so far:

1. Desaturate via  Image -> Adjustments -> Desaturate
2. Convert to grayscale via Image -> Mode -> Grayscale
3. Convert to Monotone via Image -> Mode -> Duotone, then select Monotone and my color
4. Make the background transparent with the magic wand tool

Here's where I'm at now:

[image]

The thing that I'm not happy about is that there are still multiple shades of blue there. I want it to be just one single color on transparent background. Just one shade of blue (or whatever color I pick).

Comment: there's no need to desaturate before switching to grayscale mode, that's what will happen anyway.

Comment: I'd first ask those brands/companies if they can supply  monochrome versions of their logos, preferably in a vector format to avoid quality loss. Also, professionally created brands/CIs may use  specially  designed monochrome versions that vary not only in colour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a 'Threshold' adjustment layer on top. You'll find it in he layers palette:

[image: location of threshold in th elayers palette]

This will cause you to lose all anti-aliasing, though, for the layer reduces all variance and allows only white and your chosen monotone colour.

**edit:**

If you want to keep the anti-aliasing and don't mind fine-tuning settings for each image, you'd be better off with a curves layer instead. I had some succes with your example using a curve like this one:

[image: curves layer settings]

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. As I said, the threshold does the trick in the current situation. But maybe I'll need to employ the fine tuning in the future, or it helps someone who finds this.

Answer (score 4):

The fastes method (which may even be scriptable for batch conversion) I can think of to make a simple logo monochrome is using the bucket fill tool:

1. Select background by color.
2. Make background transparent.
3. Invert selection:

   [image]
4. Fill with desired color:

   [image]

Better results may be obtained by tracing the image to vector and then apply one single object color.

Answer (score -2):

Try using a color overlay via the layer options.

Comment: Hi Dana, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. I'm sorry, but this will not work with the original image: the oberlay will cover the entire image. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!